# Arbitrary parametrized functions determined by n points

Tags: functions, monotone-functions, smooth-functions

An arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$ is determined by $n+1$ points. In some sense, one can think of the polynomial as having $n+1$ parameters - the $n+1$ coefficients associated to it. Is there a generalization of this to arbitrary families of functions with $n$ parameters?

For example, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, the functions of the form $g(a, b, x) = e^{x/a} + b$ can be thought of as a family of functions with two parameters. Given any member of this family, we can determine the function (by determining $a,b$) by given any two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$. (First determine $a$ with $e^{x_2/a} - e^{x_1/a} = y_2-y_1$, since $e^{x_2/a} - e^{x_1/a}$ is monotonic in $a$ , and then determine $b$).

Is it generally true that for any such family with $n$ parameters, we can determine the parameters of a member of said family from $n$ points? What if we restrict to smooth, non-decreasing or strictly increasing functions? What other conditions would be needed?

Comment: Well if you instead considered $f_k(x) = x^k$ to be a $1$-parameter family, you would not be able to find $k$ from the $2$ points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: That's a good point - in the application I am thinking of it is OK to restrict the potential set of points we are given, ie, I can say "given a point that is not the origin...."